# Recommendation for Pseudo Code Editor for Development

Tags: editor, text-editor

Is there an Open Source "Pseudo Code" Editor with "Syntax Highlighting" and "Auto Complete"?
Maybe even a pack for Notepad++ or any other Text Editor?

Thanks.

### Solutions

- [Pseudocode](https://github.com/Willumz/generic-pseudocode-vscode) - A simple extension for syntax highlighting of generic pseudocode. By [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487030/ben).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?   Any pseudo code you want to write would have to abide by some syntax and language constructs in order for the editor to do syntax highlighting and autocomplete.  So why don't you just pick a fairly easy to read language and use that as your pseudo code?

Comment: I think you'll have to wait till they release a specification for pseudocode ;-)  Seriously though, any IDE with syntax highlighting for VB, C# or Java would probably do a pretty good job, given that their keywords are quite similar to most pseudocode

Comment: in Notepad++, go to Language -> UserDefinedLanguage -> Define your language. There you can configure syntax highlighting for operators, keywords, numbers, and comments. Should be enough for pseudo code. This is relevant in Notepad++ v 7.8.7 in yr 2020

Comment: [This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=willumz.generic-pseudocode) VS Code extension is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although what Daniel said is correct: Maybe something like this?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/edpcs/

If you want a "real" Pseudo-Code editor, write your own syntax-highlighting configuration for a text editor.

Comment: It does look promising. I hope it will get better and more developed.

Comment: This webapp is quite interesting as well https://code2flow.com/app

Comment: I agree with @Sangimed. Code2flow is very cool. https://code2flow.com/app

Answer (score 6):

You could easily define your own pseudocode language for NotePad++ by using their custom language plug in system. And you can turn on the built-in, language agnostic autocomplete system in -> Settings > Preferences > Backup/Autocompletion

Check out: [Creating a User Defined Language in Notepad++](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/25/creating-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo-code, by its nature, isn't formalized and won't have a real syntax, and won't have identifiers in the normal sense.  Moreover, it's idiosyncratic, so you'd have to define your own rules.  So, I'd be astonished if there was such a thing that was actually useful.  Try Python, maybe; it's about as close as you'll get to pseudo-code with a real definition, and plenty of editors handle it.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any specific to your psuedocode. It varies from developer to developer.